# Identify remote desktop client software and OS when user logs into Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server

We would like to detect what devices & what programs users are using to connect to the Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop. In particular, we would like to have an ability to detect the remote devices such as iPads, iPhones & Androids, identify the software used and allow these connections only for certain users based on combination of the client OS + software.

If it can be done in powershell to be run as part of the logon script, that'd be ideal.